# Changes in dialog box not reflecting in the executable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2003

I am using Visual Studio 2003 and facing a problem with the dialog box.
I updated some dimensions of the dialog box and those changes are reflected in the `.rc` file.
However, I still can't see those changes in the executable.

Anyone have any idea what might cause this? Thanks.

Comment: @Faisal, would you happen to build in Debug mode but then run the previously-built Release mode executable, or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

When this happens, simply go to 'Build >> Rebuild' or 'Build >> Clean' then 'Build >> Build'

Comment: Thanks guys ... the problem is resolved. The executable was expecting a setupresources.dll to be updated as well.